# IIS URL Rewriting and MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

My hosting plan has a limited number of web applications for use, but unlimited subdomains. I plan to take advantage of these subdomains by using IIS rewriting, like the following:

```
<rule name="Home Rewrite" enabled="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^home\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="home/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works fine for the most part, I can go to `http://home.mydomain.com` and it'll take me to what is essentially `http://www.mydomain.com/home` as expected.

I am publishing using Web Deploy, and I believe the host is IIS7.

The problem is that I want to take advantage of `@Html.ActionLink`, but when viewing the source, this resolves out to include the virtual directory.

So what I end up with is a site that works when I go to the original address:

`http://www.mydomain.com/home/application`

And a site that loads, but doesn't function correctly, at the redirected address:

`http://home.mydomain.com/application`

With generated URLs in the page source pointing relative to the original address:

`/home/application/Account/Login`

This applies to links to other pages/routes, bundles, basically anywhere that `~/` or `@Html.ActionLink` is used.

How do I get around this? I'm hoping to keep the use of `@Html.ActionLink` at least, I think I can live without the tildes.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution!

https://support.gearhost.com/entries/23689272-URL-Rewrite-Subdomain

My `web.config` rewrite rule required an extra line:

```
<rule name="Home Rewrite" enabled="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^home\.mydomain\.com$" />
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/home/" negate="true" /> <!-- This one! -->
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="home/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now everyone is happy :)

Comment: Okay, call me fickle, but I'm going to scrap that as a potential final solution. The links still start with `/home/`, so what I end up with is:
`http://home.mydomain.com/home/application`
It _does_ work, but it's not a URL I'm happy with.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom  `HtmlHelper` so instead of using `ActionLink` you can use `MyActionLink` and it can generate the url you need.

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution, so that the site will function correctly no matter what URL I view it from:

`http://home.mydomain.com/application`

and

`http://www.mydomain.com/home/application`

should both work.

Comment: All writing a custom `HtlmHelper` would do would change the html that is generated by `MyActionLink` it wouldn't change how your code works.